# hightlight a particular td

Tags: jquery

What I would like to do (and is of course not working) is:

- When the user changes the value of the input in a row, that then the unit price and the subtotal tds in THAT row changes the background to orange (the class for that is `.basket-table td.hightlight`).

It also needs to be highlighted for a specific time and later the bg needs to turn back to light blue.

This is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/Q4T58/

Could you please help me?
Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you have any javascript/jquery that you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/Q4T58/3/

```
$(function(){

    var delay = 2000;
    $(".basket-bsol .search-input").change(function(){

    var tr = $(this).closest("tr");

    tr.find(".price-enabled, .subtotal-price").addClass("hightlight");    

    setTimeout(function(){
          tr.find(".price-enabled, .subtotal-price").removeClass("hightlight");   
    }, delay); 

    });

});
```

Comment: @OrangeJuice - Did you get a chance to take a look at this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're looking for, but this should at least get you started. It finds the `td` elements with classes `.subtotal-price` and `.price-enabled` (which you had as orange in your example):

```
$("input[type=text]").change(function() {
   var current = $(this).closest("tr").find(".subtotal-price, .price-enabled");
   current.addClass("hightlight");
   setTimeout(function() {
      current.removeClass("hightlight"); 
   }, 1000); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `setInterval` timer and `oninput` event to determine when those fields have changed (if `oninput` is fired then `setInterval` can be cleared)

*this exam uses jQuery UI for the [highlight effect](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight)*

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/Q4T58/4/)

```
// traditional setInterval to check if input changed...
var isPriceChanged = function() {
        $('.search-input').each(function() {
            var $that = $(this),
                oldvalue = $that.data('oldvalue');

            // initialize oldvalue
            if (oldvalue === undefined) {
                $that.data('oldvalue', $that.val());
            } else {
                // update/highlight fields if value has changed
                if ($.trim($that.val()) !== $.trim(oldvalue)) {
                    highlightChangedFields($that);
                    $that.data('oldvalue', $that.val());
                }
            }
        });
    },
    // check input fields every half sec
    priceChangedTimer = setInterval(isPriceChanged, 500); 

// *new html5* 'input' event
$('.search-input').bind('input', function() {
    highlightChangedFields($(this));
    // disable traditional way if this event is called
    clearInterval(priceChangedTimer);
});

var timer = undefined,
    highlightChangedFields = function($that) {
        var $row = $that.closest('.basket-row')
            $price = $row.find('.price-enabled'),
            $subtotal = $row.find('.subtotal-price'),
            $fields = $.merge($price, $subtotal);

        // clear previous timers
        clearTimeout(timer);

        // update price values
        // probably use some kind of money formatter
        // such as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript
        $price.text('£' + $that.val());
        $subtotal.text('£' + $that.val());

        // highlight price fields
        $fields.stop(true, true).effect('highlight', {color: '#ffbc0a'}, 2000);
    };
```